# If I create a constexpr function to only generate a compile time constant, shouldn't there be a way to generate a constexpr value from the parameters?

Tags: c++, c++14

I understand that `constexpr` function return values cannot be compile time constants until the function has returned.  Thus this works:

```
template <typename...Ts>
constexpr auto f(Ts&&...args) {
    auto value = std::tuple<Ts...>(args...);
    return some_constexpr_transform_function(value);
}
constexpr auto vf = f(1, 2.3, 4);
```

However, for the case where the function's parameters *are only* compile time constants, and thus the function is capable of returning a compile time constant, one should be able to take those arguments and generate a compile time constant to do some compile time magic on it.

```
template <typename...Ts>
constexpr auto g(Ts&&...args) {
    constexpr auto value = std::tuple<Ts...>(args...);
    // do some compile time magic here on value, like:
    static_assert(std::get<0>(value) == 1, "The first parameter must be 1.");
    return some_constexpr_transform_function(value);
}
constexpr auto vg = g(1, 2.3, 4);
```

This is with the understanding that this function is no longer callable with runtime parameters.  Alas this isn't the case.  Instead I have to do some ugly indirection stuff, requiring things to look messy and putting initialization out of place:

```
namespace detail {
    // Sorry future dev, I know that this init is better off below, but
    // I have to make this look ugly to do compile time validation tests.  
    constexpr auto ugly_intermediate_constexpr_value = std::make_tuple(1, 2.3, 4);
    static_assert(std::get<0>(ugly_intermediate_constexpr_value) == 1
        , "The first parameter must be 1.");      
}

template <typename...Ts>
constexpr auto h(std::tuple<Ts...>&& args) {
    return some_constexpr_transform_function(args);
}
constexpr auto vh = h(detail::ugly_intermediate_constexpr_value);
```

Is there any talk about fixing this?  This seems to be a pretty big deficiency.

NOTE: I'm currently using c++14, and I know that I didn't use the perfect forwarding idiom.  It's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Obviously currently there is no such a thing as constexpr args, but there is a proposal for that. https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1045r1.html

Comment: Interesting paper @Dmitry.  Thx.

Comment: Remove `constexpr` from `value`. Replace `static_assert` with `if(!/*...*/) throw "...";` and (optionally) `constexpr` on the function with `consteval` and you have what you want. The `static_assert` is pointless during a constant evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem with making parameters `constexpr`, one which even P1045 has trouble dealing with, has to do with things users want most to be able to do when doing constant expression coding. Consider the following code:

```
template<int v>
constexpr auto func()
{
  if constexpr(v == 0)
    return int{5};
  else
    return float{20.f};
}
```

So, what is `decltype(func)`? The answer is that there is no answer because the question is invalid. `func` is not a function; it is a *template*. Templates have no "type", so `decltype` makes no sense when applied to them.

Templates are constructs which *generate* new types/functions/variables, based on their template arguments. The above works in C++ because `func<0>` is a *different function* from `func<1>`. Therefore, `decltype(func<0>)` is a legitimate thing and can be a different type from `decltype(func<1>)`.

Consider a hypothetical `constexpr` equivalent:

```
constexpr auto func2(constexpr int v)
{
  if constexpr(v == 0)
    return int{5};
  else
    return float{20.f};
}
```

OK: what is `decltype(func2)`? There can be no answer, because what `func2` does depends on the arguments it is called with. In effect, `func2` is not a function: it is really some kind of construct which *generates* a function based on arguments it is given. And C++ already has such a language construct.

It's called a "template".

This problem relates to more than just function return types (though that's a big one for metaprogramming and reflection). Consider something as simple as:

```
constexpr void func3(constexpr size_t sz)
{
  std::array<int, sz> arr{};
  //Other stuff.
}
```

The compiler needs to generate the code to value-initialize `arr`. But that will have to have a size that depends on `sz`. Indeed, the amount of *stack space* that is taken up depends on `sz`. So... how does that work?

Each function call with a different `sz` value effectively has to regenerate the internals of the function... in exactly the same way as a template would for a different template argument value.

Basically, any attempt to make `constexpr` parameters is going to confront the reality that these are just template parameters. It's going to have to build a mechanism that *exactly parallels* template instantiation.

And with C++20 already having class types as non-type template parameters, the only thing that's wanting is a bit of syntactic sugar, allowing you to invoke `func(0)` rather than `func<0>()`.

So just use template parameters.

Comment: Interesting.  Hadn't considered returning a different type for a different value parameter set.  Yes, that makes this problem much more nuanced.

Comment: @Adrian: It's not *just* return values. It's also different internals. A `constexpr` value can be used to generate different templates. You could do `tuple_element_t<param, decltype(some_tuple)>`, and those could be different types based on the `constexpr` `param`. Most cases where a parameter *needs* to be `constexpr` will have to be able to do manifestly different things internally even on a type level. Even something as simple as a local `array<int, param>` would take up different amounts of stack space.

Comment: To be honest, I can't see why any of that is a problem. As you said it is pretty much like foo<arg>(), well why can't we just make the compiler do some kind of replacement from auto foo(constexpr Type t){...} to tempalte <Type t> constexpr auto foo(Type){...}

Comment: @Dmitry: Have you ever tried to invoke `obj.member<30>()`? It's not quite that simple, is it? Especially if `obj` itself is a type defined by a template parameter.

Comment: @NicolBolas Hmmm I'm a bit confused
    struct S { template <size_t N> size_t foo() { return N; }; };
    Obj obj;
    obj.foo<30>()

Comment: What did you mean by this: `...with C++20 already having class types as non-type template parameters...`?

Comment: @Adrian: Before C++20, non-type template parameters had to be basic types like `int` or pointers. C++20 added the ability to have user-defined types as NTTPs, so your ability to pass objects as constexpr template parameters improved substantially.